# Can we use a CASE in BETWEEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, between

I know that we can use BETWEEN inside a CASE. But I have a situation where I want to do the other way round. I know that we can't return more than one value from case statement.But how to achieve the below situation??

```
select * from #Results
where Num Between 
case when @StartIndex>0 then 
((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount))+ 1)) AND (@StartIndex * @PageCount)
else
((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount)+ 1) AND  (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount)+ 1)
```

Comment: Yes you can use it

Comment: What is the logic you want to implement in your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If `@StartIndex>0` then Num should be `BETWEEN` the 2 values `(((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount))+ 1)) AND (@StartIndex * @PageCount)` else `(((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount)+ 1) AND  (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount)+ 1)`

Comment: You have a typo in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `AND/OR` logic

```
SELECT * 
FROM   #results 
WHERE  ( num BETWEEN ( ( @StartIndex - 1 ) * @PageCount ) + 1 AND @StartIndex * @PageCount 
         AND @StartIndex > 0 ) 
        OR ( num BETWEEN ( ( @StartIndex - 1 ) * @PageCount ) + 1 AND ( ( @StartIndex - 1 ) * @PageCount ) + 1 
             AND @StartIndex <= 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
declare @start int,
        @end int

set @start = ((@StartIndex -1)*PageCount) + 1
set @end  = case when @StartIndex>0 then @StartIndex * @PageCount 
                 else ((@StartIndex -1)*@PageCount) +1 end

select * from #Results
where Num Between @start and @end
```

Comment: Is this the simplest method? Can't we achieve it without declaring 2 more variables?

Comment: some times you need your query to be more readable, if you want to get it in one step, I think the other answers are good to try, but from my side, the code should be readable and easy to maintain

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE CASE WHEN @StartIndex > 0 AND
           Num BETWEEN (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount) + 1) AND
                       (@StartIndex * @PageCount)
           THEN TRUE
           WHEN @StartIndex > 0 AND
           Num BETWEEN (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount) + 1) AND
                       (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount) + 1)
           THEN TRUE
           ELSE FALSE    -- other conditions?
      END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way, you just have to use case for second condition only because you have first condition same

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Results
WHERE Num BETWEEN (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount)+ 1) AND 
CASE WHEN @StartIndex > 0 THEN 
    (@StartIndex * @PageCount) 
ELSE 
    (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount)+ 1) 
END
```

In your code two closing brackets are extra or not operated properly '(((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount))+ 1))' and the way you are operating the case also not allowed. In the way of different condition:

```
SELECT * FROM #Results
WHERE Num BETWEEN 
    CASE WHEN @StartIndex>0 THEN 
        (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount)+ 1) 
    ELSE  
        (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount)+ 1) 
    END
    AND 
    CASE WHEN @StartIndex>0 THEN 
        (@StartIndex * @PageCount) 
    ELSE 
        (((@StartIndex-1) * @PageCount)+ 1) 
    END
```

Comment: What if both the values are different in both case??

Comment: @JibinBalachandran I have added one more part for different cases please check. Thanks